# Javadoc @see object method

Tags: java, javadoc

I would like to link a method of another object using @see from a comment block
@see is only giving me the option to link classes, not methods.
What is the hack?

```
public class A {
  B bee;

  /**
   * Just invoking methodB on bee.
   * @see B.methodB() <-- There
   */
  public methodA() {
     bee.methodB();
  }
}

public class B {
  /**
   * The real stuff
   */
  public methodB() {
    // real stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use hashes instead of dots, as in:  `@see B#methodB()`

Comment: What about in situations where we want to refer to a public static function of a class? Intellij IDE doesn't seem to recognize the `@see MyClass.foo()` format. Attempting to use a `#` results in `foo()` not being listed, as it is not a non-static member of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 17):

You need to use # instead of .

```
@see B#methodB()
```

See the documentation for `@see` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see).

Comment: when I do this in Spring Tools Suite (eclipse derivative) I displays the reference but it is not a clickable link like a local method is.

Answer (score 7):

This applies to javadocs in Eclipse.

Press # and <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> to get a "link" to a Member-Method of current context.

In a Javadoc press

SDF<kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>#gDFS <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>Symbol

to create the link:

```
{@link SimpleDateFormat#getDateFormatSymbols() Symbol}
```

Comment: Nice keys, how do you get those?

Comment: Capital letters describs java naming elements, in stackoverflow its the html-tag "kbd".

Comment: I assume this is in eclipse, with default key bindings. You should really specify.